# What Django queryset(s) would be the functional equivalent to MySQL stored procedure that requires an input?

Tags: mysql, django-queryset

I have a MySQL database that has tables listing standalone generators, RPG systems and genres among other things.  Several of my tables are connecting in someway to my Genre table. In Django, I would like to build a template that takes the genre's slug as an argument and displays lists of all relevant charts, RPG systems, modules, etc. found in the database as a kind of easy reference.  I've never seriously worked with Django querysets and I'm having problems choosing the right methods to get what I need.

I am running MySQL version 8.0.17 (MySQL Community Server - GPL), and my Django version is (2, 2, 6, 'final', 0).

This is a stored procedure that would take the genre_slug as an argument and return a list of tables that fit the genre:

```
DELIMITER @@

CREATE PROCEDURE genres_tables
#genre_slug is provided by the link clicked on by the user
(IN slug VARCHAR(72))
BEGIN
SELECT g.genre, t.`table_name`
FROM generators_genre g
#Joins to get to D100Generator table
INNER JOIN generators_d100generator t
ON g.genre=t.genre_id_id
WHERE t.genre_id_id = (
    SELECT genre
    FROM generators_genre
    WHERE genre_slug = slug); /*The slug is provided by the link clicked on*/
END @@

DELIMITER ;
```

The Genre and table(D100Generator) models:

```
class Genre(models.Model):
    genre = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    genre_name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    genre_slug = models.SlugField('leave this blank, autosaves new slug', max_length=72, unique=True, blank=True, null=True)

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if not self.genre:
            #Newly created object, so set slug
            self.genre_slug = slugify(self.genre_name)

        super(Genre, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
    def __str__(self):
        return self.genre_name

class D100Generator(models.Model):
    d_100_id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    table_name = models.CharField('table name', max_length=100)
    system_id = models.ForeignKey(System, on_delete=models.CASCADE, blank=True, null=True)
    genre_id = models.ForeignKey(Genre, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    chart_type = models.CharField('Die used', max_length=15)
    chart_instructions = models.TextField('Chart instructions & explanation')
    roll_1 = models.TextField('1', blank=True, null=True)
...
    roll_110 = models.TextField('110', blank=True, null=True)
    table_slug = models.SlugField('leave this blank, autosaves new slug', max_length=72, unique=True, blank=True, null=True)

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if not self.d_100_id:
            #Newly created object, so set slug
            self.table_slug = slugify(self.table_name)

        super(D100Generator, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
    def __str__(self):
        return self.table_name
```

views.py:

```
from django.shortcuts import get_object_or_404, render
from .models import Genre, D100Generator

def genre(request, slug):
    genre_page = get_object_or_404(Genre, pk=slug)
    chosen_genre = Genre.objects.get(genre_slug__exact=slug)
    genre_tables = D100Generator.objects.get(genre_id__exact=chosen_genre.genre)

    context = {
        'genre_page': genre_page,
        'genre_tables': genre_tables,
    }
    return render (request, 'generators/genre.html', context)
```

genre.html template:

```
<h1>{{ genre_page.genre_name }}</h1>

<p>This genre is referenced by the following:</p>

<h2>Tables</h2>
<ul>
{% for table in genre_tables %}
    <li><a href="{% url 'generators:table' table_slug=table.pk %}">{{ table.table_name }}</a></li>
{% endfor %}
</ul>
```

On the genre.html page, I get the error "DoesNotExist at /generators/genre/9

Genre matching query does not exist."

I expected the URL to show the genre_slug instead of the primary key 'genre' in the given URL.  Maybe I'm using the wrong logic focusing on the genre_slug?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On my views.py:

```
def genre(request, genre_slug):
    genre_page = get_object_or_404(Genre, pk=genre_slug)
    g = genre_slug
    genre_tables = D100Generator.objects.filter(genre_id__exact=g)

    context = {
        'genre_page': genre_page,
        'genre_tables': genre_tables,
    }
    return render (request, 'generators/genre.html', context)
```